# How to Download a video from a web site using termial

Tags: linux, web-services

for example how to download a video from a youtube provided the Url of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `youtube-dl` `youtubeUrl`. To install youtube-dl.
Run these commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`

Comment: do this work only for youtube or with any other site?

Comment: only youtube. Use `wget` to download any video from a public URL.

Comment: When I use wget 'url ' its downloading the html of that page but not the video. you give example for that

Comment: Every video cannot be downloaded unless it's a file uploaded to a server. Youtube-dl caches the stream of youtube then attaches all the frames to make a video. `wget` only downloads the file. If you provide an `html` url then html file will be downloaded.

Comment: Ok , but i want to download the youtube video using wget command how can i do that? Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't see any benefit of using `wget` instead of `youtube-dl`. Downloading a streamed video is not a straight forward task. Please use `youtube-dl`.